# How to get all name of RecordType in a private Database CloudKit

Tags: ios8, icloud, cloudkit, ckquery, ckrecord

I would like to know how I can get an array with all the name of record type in my private database in Cloud Kit for read all my data ?

I save my data :

```
CKRecord* fav1 = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Favoris1"];

[fav1 setObject:@"Favoris 1 name"forKey:@"name"];
[fav1 setObject:@"2003 year"forKey:@"year"];

[self.privateDatabase saveRecord:fav1
               completionHandler:^(CKRecord *savedState, NSError *error) {
                   if (error) {
                       NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING: %@", error);

                   }
                   else{
                       NSLog(@"SAVE OK");
                   }
               }];
```

I read my data :

```
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Favoris1" predicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"]];
[self.privateDatabase performQuery:query
                      inZoneWithID:nil
                 completionHandler:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         NSLog(@"results query %@", results);
         NSLog(@"--> %@",[[results objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]);
         NSLog(@"--> %@",[[results objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"year"]);
     }

     else
     {
         NSLog(@"FETCH ERROR: %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

I would like to save an other record with another properties like :

```
CKRecord* fav2 = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Favoris2"];
[fav2 setObject:@"Favoris 2 name"forKey:@"name"];
[fav2 setObject:@"2005 year"forKey:@"year"];
```

How can I have an array with Favoris1 and Favoris2 for read all my record after I have saved ?

Answer (score 0):

in CloudKit there is no function that will return all the available recordType's from a database. You can also not query multiple recordTypes at the same time. You have to perform 2 queries. What you could do is join the resulting arrays together if you need something like that.

Since the objects are the same, it would be better if you just used 1 recordType and add an extra field that would specify your custom type (Favoris1 or Favoris2) Then you could query just the recordType and see in the returned field what custom type it is.